# Custom LINQ .Include() extension

Tags: linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

Given the following pseudo code, how could i call this function with `.Include` and pass it on to `ctx.Table`

```
public class Complicated
{
// fields here
}


public IEnumerable<Complicated> GetComplicatedData<T>()
{

   using(MyDbCtx ctx = new MyDbCtx())
   {
      return ctx.Set<T>().Select(p=> new Complicated { /* fill */ }).ToList();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Your method is doing projection so even if you find the way your include will never be used. If you want to use Include you must use a method this way:

```
ctx.Table.Include(...).ToList().Select(p => new Complicated { ... });
```

This example doesn't make much sense because you know what data you need to fill your `Complicated` item so you can either fill them directly by linq-to-entites without using `Include` at all or you know upfront what includes will you need to fill your `Complicated` entity by linq-to-objects.

There is no eager or lazy loading for custom projected classes.

Comment: What if my type were generic and i pass it to the getcomplicated method. there should be a way to pass the include properties as a parameter? i changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: If your type is generic your T must be constrained so that you can use it within method to fill `Complicated` entity = my answer is still same but it targets parent (constraint) for the T.

Comment: So there is no way i can pass an include through my function to the context?

Comment: Not direct way. You can create custom extension for `IEnumerable` which will only store these include requirements somewhere and your method will take them from the storage and use them. The question is if it make sense (as I pointed in my answer)?